# databinding in seam project

Tags: html, data-binding, seam

i am working on a seam project in which i have to develop an ADD MODIFY and DELETE xthml pages , i have many tables in the database for which i have to create this xhtml pages , as the main templates is , same what changes is the column names  .
for this purpose i am thinking of making a common xhtml page for all the tables and generate the xhtml page for a particular table through databinding on run time .

is it possible to do this ?  i tried it but , databinding doesn't support many a tabs of xhtml .
can i generate the ids and values at runtime.
if not possible with databinding , what other possible methods could be there , please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't generate the xhtml files at runtime. They need to exist at deploy time.

If using seam 2 take a look at chapter 13 of seam 2 reference: "the seam application framework".

I don't know about seam 3.